# Test program for software defined radio USRP X310

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, usrp, uhd

I want to run the first test program for my software defined radio USRP X310 which is given on the company's website: https://kb.ettus.com/Getting_Started_with_UHD_and_C%2B%2B

I work with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows. I have installed, build and linked in VS2015 the boost and UHD libraries (UHD version 3.10.1.1 and boost version 1.63.0).

Trying to debug the program I get several error messages about 'unresolved external symbols'. I tried to locate the problem and ended up with very basic code example and noticed that the function 'uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(device_args)' does not work. In addition 'uhd::set_thread_priority_safe()' does not work either.

It seems to me that the code itself is not the problem. Does anyone know where these errors come from?

My code 
    `#include <uhd/utils/safe_main.hpp>`

```
`#include <uhd/usrp/multi_usrp.hpp>`
`#include <uhd/utils/thread_priority.hpp>`
`#include <csignal>`
`#include <iostream>`

int UHD_SAFE_MAIN(int argc, char *argv[]) {
uhd::set_thread_priority_safe();

std::string device_args("addr=192.168.10.2");
uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::sptr usrp = uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(device_args);
return 0;
}
```

Error messages (I am sorry that they are German. I translated them which is written in brackets):

```
Fehler (error)  LNK2019 Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol (link 
to unresolved external symbol) ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall 
uhd::device_addr_t::device_addr_t(class std::basic_string<char,struct 
std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??
0device_addr_t@uhd@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)" in Funktion (in function) ""int __cdecl 
_main(int,char * * const)" (?_main@@YAHHQAPAD@Z)".  line 1 

Fehler (error)  LNK2019 Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol (link             
to unresolved external symbol)  ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall 
uhd::device_addr_t::~device_addr_t(void)" (__imp_??
1device_addr_t@uhd@@QAE@XZ)" in Funktion (in function) ""int __cdecl 
_main(int,char * * const)" (?_main@@YAHHQAPAD@Z)". line 1

Fehler (error)  LNK2019 Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol (link 
to unresolved external symbol)  ""__declspec(dllimport) public: static class 
boost::shared_ptr<class uhd::usrp::multi_usrp> __cdecl 
uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(class uhd::device_addr_t const &)" (__imp_?
make@multi_usrp@usrp@uhd@@SA?AV?
$shared_ptr@Vmulti_usrp@usrp@uhd@@@boost@@ABVdevice_addr_t@3@@Z)" in 
Funktion (in function)  ""int __cdecl _main(int,char * * const)" (?
_main@@YAHHQAPAD@Z)". line 1

Fehler (error)  LNK2019 Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol (link 
to unresolved external symbol)""__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl 
uhd::set_thread_priority_safe(float,bool)" (__imp_?
set_thread_priority_safe@uhd@@YA_NM_N@Z)" in Funktion ""int __cdecl 
_main(int,char * * const)" (?_main@@YAHHQAPAD@Z)". line 1 

LNK1120 4 nicht aufgelöste Externe (4 unresolved external symbols) line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem comes if you want to build it in Debug-Mode. The UHD you are linking to are build for Release-Mode, so you have to build your project in Release-Mode too. I had the same problem, and now i'm trying to build the UHD for VS2015 in Debug and Release mode, to be able to link in Debug-Mode, to the Debug-Objects and in Release-Mode to Release-Objects. But i don't get it build in Debug neither in Release-Mode with this TUT (https://kb.ettus.com/Building_and_Installing_the_USRP_Open_Source_Toolchain_(UHD_and_GNU_Radio)_on_Windows). I have to look for this. IF you will get it to work, it would be nice if you can tell how you have done it ( I'm german too).
Hope this helps you, even your post is 6 months old :D.